Error in OpenTelemetry With Istio: sending queue is full
I'm using OpenTelemetry as a tracing collector in istio, but after running OpenTelemetry Collector for a while, the logs for istio-ingressgateway and the logs for Sidecar (istio-proxy) in the Pod keep printing OcAgent trace exporter: Export() failed: UNKNOWN: sending queue is full. I also tried to change the queue_size field in the OpenTelemetry Config, but it didn't fix the problem.
This issue also caused the ingressgateway logs to not print properly anymore.
My OpenTelemetry Config File
receivers:
  opencensus:
    max_recv_msg_size_mib: 10
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:55678
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
processors:
  memory_limiter:
    limit_mib: 32000
    spike_limit_mib: 1000
    check_interval: 2s
exporters:
  zipkin/nontls:
    sending_queue:
      queue_size: 10000
    endpoint: <A Jaeger Backend>
  kafka:
    sending_queue:
      queue_size: 10000
      ......
  logging:
    loglevel: debug
service:
  pipelines:
    ....

Part of My Istio Operator Yaml:
meshConfig:
    accessLogEncoding: JSON
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    accessLogFormat: ...
    defaultConfig:
      holdApplicationUntilProxyStarts: true
      proxyMetadata:
        EXIT_ON_ZERO_ACTIVE_CONNECTIONS: 'true'
        ISTIO_META_DNS_AUTO_ALLOCATE: 'true'
        ISTIO_META_DNS_CAPTURE: 'true'
      tracing:
        max_path_tag_length: 256
        openCensusAgent:
          address: dns:opentelemetry-collector.istio-system.svc.cluster.local:55678
          context:
            - B3
        sampling: 100
    defaultProviders:
      tracing:
        - opencensus
    enableTracing: true
    extensionProviders:
      - name: opencensus
        opencensus:
          context:
            - B3
          port: 55678
          service: opentelemetry-collector.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
      - envoyExtAuthzGrpc:
          port: '9898'
          service: local-opa-grpc.local
        name: opa.local
  profile: default
  tag: 1.15.0
  values:
      .....
      tracer:
        zipkin:
          address: jaeger-collector-headless.jaeger-system.svc.cluster.local:9411

Any ideas and directions on how to troubleshoot this? Or how can I fix this issue. Thanks in advance!

Have you tried decreasing the sampling from 100 to something smaller?
